# How to populate quiz externally in Moodle?

Tags: php, moodle

I have created quiz in Moodle externally, now I want to add questions to the  quiz too externally. I tried it using save_questions() function which is inside file questiontypebase.php file in question folder. but is not working properly. 
Is there any other function or it is the right one? if it is right one how to use it? any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a function `quiz_add_quiz_question` in quiz\locallib.php

Comment: thank your for your reply. I have solve the problem. save_question() is prefect. my problem was with object I was using to call the function.